# Is there a benefit to using LoadLibrary instead of linking?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll

Using dependency walker I noticed some apps that definitely use Direct3D 11, but only link to Direct3D 9's library dll.

Do I gain something by linking? Would there be any benefit in using LoadLibrary?

Why might I choose one method over the other?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic CS subjects, answerable by search

Comment: You are correct. I guess when I was writing the question, it was after I failed at coming up with the correct terms to search for. Thanks for the gentle kick. :D

Comment: I also just realised that would be the reason the app would be linking to Direct3D 9 and not 11... Since v9 would be a minimum requirement, and they could upgrade the experience if you had 11 installed -- as opposed to a fatal launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think, if you link DLL statically to your application you will not be able to even start the application if any DLL is missing. In case of manual LoadLibrary the application can start, check DLL availability and write message to log, show a good error description to user or even use another DLL set, e.g. another version of DLLs with different names instead of newest ones.

Comment: Mostly true, especialy the rationale why loadlibrary might be breffered sometimes. The downside is, that dynamic linking is often more complex to implement. If it is just for displaying an error message, there are ways to do this even with static linked libs.